# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir el valor ASCII de un hexadecimal con C++?

Tags: c++

Suponiendo que tengo un arreglo o vector de números hexadecimales, los cuales representan un caracter de código ASCII ¿Cómo puedo obtener el caracter usando el hexadecimal? Voy a utilizar pseudocódigo para mi ejemplo:

```
hexadecimales = [0x54, 0x45] // ['T', 'E']
```

Cómo podría utilizar este arreglo o vector de números hexadecimales para poder imprimir su caracter utilizando un for loop:

```
for(auto i : hexadecimales)
    std::cout << i;
```

Lo que tendría que imprimir sería `TE`.

Answer (score 1):

Solo debes declarar el vector que recibirá tus hexagesimales de tipo char

```
char vals[2] = { 0x54, 0x45 };
for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
  std::cout << vals[i];
}
return 0;
```

salida
    TE

Answer (score 1):

Ya que estás utilizando el bucle `for` de rango ([range-based for](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/cpp/range-based-for-statement-cpp)), entonces te voy a sugerir, como alternativa a la otra respuesta, hacer uso de contenedores. En este caso voy a utilizar el contenedor `vector` que se encuentra disponible en la cabecera `<vector>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>      

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> hexadecimales = {0x54, 0x45};
    for(auto i : hexadecimales)
        std::cout << (char)i;

    return 0;
}
```

Como se puede apreciar en el código anterior, solo basta castear el valor de `i` a tipo `char`.

Comment: "*Ya que estás utilizando el bucle `for` de rango, entonces es conveniente trabajar con contenedores*", esto es del todo falso. Al bucle `for` de rango le es indiferente si recibe una formación, un contenedor o una clase que tenga funciones miembro llamadas `begin` y `end`: su comportamiento no variará, no es ni más ni menos conveniente.

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus creo que me expresé mal. Mi intención era sugerir una alternativa a la otra respuesta. Por otro parte, pensaba que el bucle `for` de rango (que es lo que el OP usa) no se podía aplicar con arrays "estilo C", sin embargo mi idea era errónea. Fue cuestión de googlear y darme cuenta que usted tiene razón. Voy a editar mi post para dejar en claro mi intención.

Comment: No estás del todo equivocado ni del todo en lo cierto respecto a las formaciones "estilo C". Sólo se pueden usar aquellas cuyo tamaño se conozca en tiempo de compilación.